# Firebase - How to insert multiple same child in firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is my current firebase structure.

I want to add multiple new PK68,but after using "mdatabaseReference.push().setValue(cart);" auto generate the childId with "MElGGtNwri7YBp0nX_p" not PK68.

How can I insert another PK68 with no overwrite existing PK68??

```
User
    -MEMhyAzd7blj_vRbbev
      email:test@gmail.com
      name:Test
       -Cart
         -PK68
         -PK88
         -MElGGtNwri7YBp0nX_p
```

Answer (score 0):

`push()` generates a reference with a new unique, random ID every time you call it.  You can't use it to change data under an existing node, since it always generates a new ID.

If you want to change the data under "-MEMhyAzd7blj_vRbbev", you will need to build a path using exactly that string, then use `setValue()` or `update()` to change the data under the specific path you provide.

```
mdatabaseReference.child("-MEMhyAzd7blj_vRbbev").child("Cart")...
```

If you don't know the name of the child, you'll have to query to find it.

Comment: I dont want to overwrite my existing PK68, I want to remain the existing PK68 and insert another new PK68, which mean got 2 PK68

Comment: You can't have two children under a node with the same name.  Each sibling child name must be unique.